# Бо́льшая половина

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов, словосочетания

— Нету такой вещи, как бо́льшая половина, — говорит учительница классу. — Половины одинаковые, равные. Если одна из них больше, то значит уже не половина. Это элементарно. Почему же бо́льшая половина класса этого не понимает?

Один из моих любимых анекдотов. А вот откуда вообще возникло выражение **бо́льшая половина**? Ведь это элементарно, что такой половины быть не может.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не все так просто. Половина - не обязательно точно 1/2. Можно воспринимать и как часть...

Согласен, в серьезных текстах я бы избегал подобных вольностей. Но в быту я принимаю "половина" как одну часть - но строго **из двух**!

"Четвертовать его на три половины!" (С)

Comment: Нда, уж тут на самом деле интересная математика получается! :) Спасибо за ответ!

Answer (score 1):

**Бо́льшая/ме́ньшая половина**
Слово "половина" означает *одна вторая часть, одна из двух равных частей*: одна половина, первая или вторая половина, обе половины.

Вот что пишет [Розенталь](http://litresp.ru/chitat/ru/%D0%A0/rozentalj-ditmar-eljyashevich/spravochnik-po-pravopisaniyu-i-literaturnoj-pravke-dlya-rabotnikov-pechati/158) ("Справочник по правописанию и литературной правке для работников печати"):
...сочетания «большая половина» и «меньшая половина» в прошлом не употреблялись, поскольку слово половина имело основное значение «одна из двух равных частей чего-либо».
В дальнейшем в тех случаях, когда употребление этого слова не связывалось с его терминологическим характером, оно стало приобретать расширительное значение «одна из двух частей целого». Например, у В. И. Ленина: «Этого мало, потому что перед нами сейчас стоит вторая, большая половина задачи, большая по трудности»; «Тем самым, что мы сбросили власть эксплуататоров, мы сделали уже большую половину работы» (Полн. собр. соч., т. 42, стр. 5). Ср. в художественной литературе: Большая половина фабрики… была в огне (Б. Полевой).

И всё-таки большинство словарей не рекомендует употреблять это словосочетание.

Бо́льшая половина (разг. неправ.) — правильно [бо́льшая часть](https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0/%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B9), больше половины.

***Следует запомнить***: слово [половина](https://books.google.ee/books?id=-8Q0DwAAQBAJ&pg=PA6&lpg=PA6&dq=%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8B%20%D1%81%D0%BE%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BC%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0&source=bl&ots=RxiXfaC122&sig=9mEJIJ2ecLim94Z4WYWNla0xm0E&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiy2NfG-b3fAhXUAhAIHUDlBoMQ6AEwBnoECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8B%20%D1%81%D0%BE%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BC%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0&f=false) не употребляется с прилагательными **бо́льшая** и **ме́ньшая** ("Русская речь в эфире. Комплексный справочник").

[**Вопрос № 285018**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0)
"..бОльшую половину того, что мы для Вас..." Допустимо выражение "бОльшая половина"?

**Ответ справочной службы русского языка**
Это некорректное сочетание. Половина не может быть большей или меньшей. Правильно: большую часть.